# How to allow client subdomain to link to my wildcard domain in saas

Tags: ssl, subdomain, wildcard, saas, cname

I have saas application **mysaas.com**. It has a wildcard dns entry to support ***.mysaas.com**. This allows my clients to have URL's as per their company name such as **client1.mysaas.com** or **client2.mysaas.com** and so on. So far so good.

Next I purchased a wildcard ssl to secure ***.mysaas.com**, and that worked as well without a hitch

Now comes the problem, my clients want to whitelabel my software ie they want to create a subdomain at their end ie **newapp.client1.com** and have it open my site ie **client1.mysaas.com**

This does not seem possible as my wildcard ssl is for ***.mysaas.com** so I do not think it can handle **newapp.client1.com**. But then I see google suite, allowing clients to map their custom subdomains to google suite. I was wondering how is this possible. Can someone please help.

Answer (score -1):

Your client wants to redirect his/her domain to your domain client1.mysaas.com (which is already secured with wildcard SSL). So it's not a problem. He/she can do it through 301 redirect and for that, you don't have to do anything.

And if you want to take help of google suit for that then follow one by one step from here https://support.google.com/a/answer/186990?hl=en

Comment: Thats not correct, as the receiving server needs to have allowed incoming requests from "newapp.client1.com"

Comment: Then convince the client to avoid to make subdomain  newapp.client1.com and make their own website in place of redirecting it to your website client1.mysaas.com